# NASM not printing out all my instructions; Skipping a block of code

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm working on a toy NASM program that will add up all the values in a specific program.
I'm playing around with NASM now as I build my program to get a feel for how everything works.

SO far in my program, I have place a series of outputs that say "Works" so I can narrow down where the error is.

Currently I expect to see five printouts of "Work" however I'm only seeing four. Apparently, the the code under `Output:` is failing to print, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

```
segment .data
    ;studentInfo: db 10,'Program by Raphael Stein', 10, '6079652', 10, 10 ;
    ;infoLen: equ $-studentInfo

    NUM_ROWS: equ 5
    NUM_COLUMNS: equ 5
    NUM_ROW_BYTES: equ 10

    ;Default matrix
    matrix: dw  5, 4, 9, 7, 2
        dw  1, 4, 6, 8, 7
        dw  9, 9, 2, 3, 7
        dw  6, 5, 8, 3, 4
        dw  1, 2, 8, 2, 6   
    matrixLen: equ $-matrix

    sum:    db "The sum of the last column is: ", 10

    ;FOR TESTING
    works: db 'Works!', 10
    worksLen: equ $-works

segment .bss
    counter resb 1

segment .text
    global main

main:
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov eax, 4      ; system call 4
    mov ebx, 1      ; standard output 
    mov ecx, works      ; Works!            1
    mov edx, worksLen
    int 0x80
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;mov CX, NUM_ROWS           ;Works!
    mov ECX, counter
    sub AX, AX
    sub EBX, EBX
    mov ESI, NUM_COLUMNS-1


;------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov eax, 4      ; system call 4
    mov ebx, 1      ; standard output 
    mov ecx, works      ; Works!            2
    mov edx, worksLen
    int 0x80
;------------------------------------------------------------------------


sum_loop:               
    add EAX, [matrix + EBX + ESI*2]
    add EBX, NUM_ROW_BYTES
    add ECX, 1
    cmp EAX,ECX
    mov esi, eax
    jge Output
    LOOP sum_loop

;------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov eax, 4      ; system call 4
    mov ebx, 1      ; standard output 
    mov ecx, works      ; Works!            3
    mov edx, worksLen
    int 0x80
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Output:
    mov eax, 4  
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, works
    mov edx, worksLen
    int 0x80


;------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov eax, 4      ; system call 4
    mov ebx, 1      ; standard output 
    mov ecx, works      ; Works!            4
    mov edx, worksLen
    int 0x80
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

EXIT:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues here. In no particular order:

- You really want to abstract away the ad-hoc debug print instruction sequence into a separate function. This would be a good opportunity to practice that. Doing so would eliminate code duplication and probably eliminate some bugs. Such as...
- Under the sum_loop label, the first instruction adds to EAX. EAX is 4, according to the most recent modification (which looks like a print copy/paste).
- So after that first ADD instruction, EAX = 4 + address_of(matrix) + EBX + ESI*2. That's going to be... a sizable quantity (the address will make it big). The code compares it against ECX which contains... the offset of the 'works' string. Again, this looks like a mistake because of copy/paste. ECX was probably supposed to be counter, defined in the previous block.
- The 'jge Output' instruction takes results from the previous CMP instruction, which was "CMP EAX, ECX". The net effect of this is: "if (EAX >= ECX) then goto Output". The way that the pointers are arranged in the .data section combined with the (sometimes accidental) math implies that this is true. This means...
- The code under the Output label is being executed. At least, my reading indicates that. Your various debug prints don't really give any data of which is triggering. I would expect that the debug print block *before* the Output label is not being executed.
- It might have been a blessing that sum_loop was inadvertently short-circuited. Otherwise, it would never terminate. Read up on the x86 LOOP instruction-- in decrements ECX and if ECX is not 0, it branches. Notice that you are adding 1 to ECX through each iteration. So, it's doing: "ECX += 1; if (--ECX != 0) then loop". This will never terminate.

Good start and initiative. Keep practicing.